# AngularJS Directive not found when attempting to run test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm following the [phone-cat angular js](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) example and trying to adapt it for testing in my situation.

My **karma.conf.js** file:

```
//jshint strict: false
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './app',

    files: [
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mocks/1.6.9/angular-mocks.min.js',

      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js',
      'libs/jquery.fileupload.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js',
      '*!(.module|.spec).js',
      '**/*.spec.js',
      '**/components/**'
    ],

    autoWatch: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ]
  });
};
```

This is my folder/file structure:

[image]

and this is my test (in file-upload.component.spec.js):

```
'use strict';

describe('fileupload', function() {

  beforeEach(module('fileUploadApp'));

  // Test the controller
  describe('FileUploadController', function() {

    it('test test', inject(function($componentController) {
      var scope = {};
      console.log("A");
      var ctrl = $componentController('FileUploadController', {
        $scope: scope
      }); // failing on this line
      console.log("B");
    }));
  });
});
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

> Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10.0.0) fileupload FileUploadController test test FAILED
>               Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=FileUploadControllerDirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20FileUploadControllerDirective
>                   at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:7:76
>                   at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:46:64
>                   at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:43:309)
>                   at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:46:126
>                   at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:43:309)
>                   at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mocks/1.6.9/angular-mocks.min.js:1:15984
>                   at UserContext. (W:/AngTest/Test/app/file-upload.component.spec.js:13:18)
>                   at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:44:390)
>                   at UserContext.o (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mocks/1.6.9/angular-mocks.min.js:1:20792)
>               Error: Declaration Location
>                   at e.inject.t.mock.inject (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mocks/1.6.9/angular-mocks.min.js:1:20326)
>                   at Suite. (W:/AngTest/Test/app/file-upload.component.spec.js:10:21)
>                   at Suite. (W:/AngTest/Test/app/file-upload.component.spec.js:8:3)
>                   at W:/AngTest/Test/app/file-upload.component.spec.js:3:1
>       Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.085 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: **[$injector:unpr]** results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee I checked to make sure it's spelled correctly and it is, so something else might be going wrong. Perhaps the files array is wrong?

Comment: `FileUploadControllerDirectiveProvider` means your module injection is wrong!

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee Yes I figure I'm doing something wrong in there somewhere.. If I'm using webpack would the 'sources' tab have the relevant js file visible by name (file-upload.component.js)?

Comment: TBH, I don't know what webpack is! But is this really AngularJs??

Answer (score 0):

should be `$componentController('fileUpload', ...`
at least as I guess `fileUpload` is your component name